# read a txt file that is dynamically fill

Tags: java, javascript

i read a file txt with java code and then i display it's content with js in html page but the content changes over time so i can't acces to file if the content was change:
the java code :
the methode that read file and return a string that containing the txt file content

```
 public static String getLog() throws IOException{
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String path=logging.getRealPath();
       InputStream ips;
        try {
            ips = new FileInputStream(path);
            InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
            String ligne;

        while((ligne=br.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append("<br>"+ligne);
                br.close();
            }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

and the js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getALLLog(){
    var arrayNew = "<%=logging.getLog()%>";
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML=arrayNew;

    }
</script>
```

the html code is like:

```
<div style="padding:15px" >
<span id="ALL" style="cursor: pointer;font-weight:bold;" onclick="getALLLog()">ALL</span>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

so the content is displayed for the first time after filling the file nothing appears

Comment: i use dwr but i get the same problem

Comment: so your problem is that it is not refreshing? at first it works but then when the file is updated the html page is not updated?

Comment: when the file was updated nothing will happen with the click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java `getLog()` function gets evaluated only once when the server generates html. After that javascript variable `arrayNew` holds the log contents. When you click on the `ALL` span you don't actually call your java server - only client-side javascript, so you just showing the same content over and over.

If you want server to be called when you click some button on the web page you need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) or just refresh the entire page.

Comment: i use dwr to solve probleme but i get the same problem